# Filtering embed.FS causes ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on HTTP server

Tags: http, go

My application runs an HTTP server that serves some static files. Most files are reachable under `/static/` but some, like `index.html`, must be reachable at the root.

This code tries to implement that by embedding the files in an `embed.FS` (for demonstration, I'm only embedding `index.html` here):

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "embed"
    "io/fs"
    "log"
)

//go:embed index.html
var files embed.FS

type primaryFiles struct {}

func (pf *primaryFiles) Open(name string) (fs.File, error) {
    // name will be "." for paths / and /index.html, I guess that's a feature
    if name == "." {
        return files.Open("index.html")
    }
    return nil, fs.ErrNotExist
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(&primaryFiles{})))
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.FS(files))))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Now when running the code, I can query the `index.html` just fine at both `http://localhost:8080/static/` and `http://localhost:8080/static/index.html`. However, at `http://localhost:8080/` and `http://localhost:8080/index.html`, the browser will give me `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. Why is that happening? How can I fix it?

I already tried to hand through the `"."`, which yields a file listing instead of the `index.html` content. I'm on `go version go1.17.3 darwin/arm64`. I also tried to figure out what's happening with `curl`:

```sh
$ curl -v http://localhost:8080/index.html
*   Trying ::1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: ./
< Date: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 22:05:50 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

$ curl -v http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying ::1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: ..//
< Date: Mon, 06 Dec 2021 22:05:12 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

This doesn't help me understand what's happening – okay. `/index.html` is redirected to `./`, that seems to make sense. But `/` being redirected to `..//` … I don't know what to make of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is *partly* documented in the [http package](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FileServer):

> As a special case, the returned file server redirects any request ending in "/index.html" to the same path, without the final "index.html".

So any request to `index.html` is not seen in my `Open` fn, since it redirects to `.`.

What the documentation does not tell that a request to `.` seems to be handled as follows:

- the directory for `.` is queried via `Open`. This should return a directory, which my original code did not and caused the error.
- if a directory is returned, it is searched for a file `index.html` and if one exists, *another request to `Open` is made*. This is what I missed.

So to fix the code, I need to pipe through the request to both `.` and `index.html` to the actual files:

```golang
func (pf *primaryFiles) Open(name string) (fs.File, error) {
    if name == "." || name == "index.html" {
        return files.Open(name)
    }
    return nil, fs.ErrNotExist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `primaryFiles.Open` implementation, when given `"."`, returns a file rather than a dir. This is an error.

The documentation on `fs.FS.Open` should lead you to `fs.ValidPath` whose godoc states the following.

> package fs // import "io/fs"
>
> func ValidPath(name string) bool
> ValidPath reports whether the given path name is valid for use in a call to
> Open.
>
> Path names passed to open are UTF-8-encoded, unrooted, slash-separated
> sequences of path elements, like “x/y/z”. Path names must not contain an
> element that is “.” or “..” or the empty string, except for the special case
> that the **root directory is named “.”**. Paths must not start or end with a
> slash: “/x” and “x/” are invalid.
>
> Note that paths are slash-separated on all systems, even Windows. Paths
> containing other characters such as backslash and colon are accepted as
> valid, but those characters must never be interpreted by an FS
> implementation as path element separators.

`net/http.FileServer` is banking on the fact that recursively redirecting on `../` should [eventually get to some directory](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e07b02ff87af594a68484dcb1e3a78d1c39abc56/src/net/http/fs.go#L623), but there is no directory to be found based on the way your `primaryFiles.Open` works. It could be argued that this is an opportunity to enhance `net/http.FileServer`, but it's not clear.

Comment: But querying `http://localhost:8080/static/` is able to return a file even though a directory is queried, and it also goes through `http.FileServer`. This answer seems to be a piece to the puzzle, but from what you say I can't deduce how to implement `primaryFiles` properly.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/static/` works file because `embed.FS` implements `fs.FS` correctly. `primaryFiles` is used at a place where a proper `fs.FS` implementation is expected, and `primaryFiles` does not implement `fs.FS` properly.

Comment: Then the question stands how to implement it *properly*. I did try to hand over the `"."` query to `embed.FS` but that only resulted in the server to respond with a file listing, which is not what I want and also not what happens at `/static/`.

Comment: See the godoc on `fs.FS` as well as godoc that it references. From the question, it seems that you seek help on fixing the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error. It seems that you now have more troubles than just fixing that. If that's the case, you should state what you want happen, not what you  do not want to happen.

Comment: I did state that my goal is to serve `index.html` at the root path, i.e. at `http://localhost:8080/`, and the purpose of `primaryFiles` is to not serve *everything* there. Your explanation is correct in describing what's happening, but it does not help me with fixing it, because I have still no idea what to do.

Comment: See https://go.dev/play/p/0QEfTAbtPMA for the fix. Although I really doubt if `http.FileServer` is the right abstraction for you given what you're trying to do.

Comment: That implementation gets rid of the error but also gets rid of the requirement to actually filter `files` – that code will serve any file in `files`. This means that it does basically the same as just doing `http.FileServer(http.FS(files))`. I still thank you for putting time into it; I have no found the actual fix and will post that as answer.